# How to use discord.Member.mobile_status in discord.py

Tags: discord.py

First of all, it may be a strange sentence because I am using a translator to write it down, but please understand.
I am developing a personal server bot using discord.py for the first time.
My question is, when a user joins the server by mobile, I want to assign a role, but I'm not sure how.
This could be a really dumb story, but I'd appreciate any help.
And I want to know the difference with `discord.Member.is_on_mobile.`

Here is my expected code. I would really appreciate your help.

```
async def shutup_mobile(message : discord.Message, member : discord.Member) :
        if discord.Member.mobile_status.online :
            # When someone joins voice_channel on mobile
            # Assign role A
            # After assigning a role, I want to send a sentence to a specific text_channel
            await message.channel.send(f'{discord.Member.name} is don't want playing game with us')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The doc's for on `is_on_mobile`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.is_on_mobile).

I feel like your entire function is wrong - if a user is joining a voice channel, why do you have a message parameter in there? You should be using the [`on_voice_update`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_voice_state_update) client event. Obviously, you could be calling the function you've provided from there - but the `message` object seem erroneous.

```py
@client.event
async def on_voice_update(member: discord.Member, before: discord.VoiceState, after: discord.VoiceState):
    # before and after are voice state objects - can be used to check if a user has joined/left a vc

    if before.channel:
        # user is already in a channel
        return
    
    # user has joined a voice channel
    if member.is_on_mobile():
        # user is on mobile - do our thing here
        guild = after.channel.guild  # get the guild object
        role_to_apply = guild.get_role(THE_ROLE_ID_YOU_WANT_GIVE)
        await member.add_roles(role_to_apply)
        the_text_channel = guild.get_channel(THE_CHANNEL_ID_YOU_WANT_TO_SEND_MESSAGE_TO)
        await the_text_channel.send(f"{member.name} is don't want playing game with us")
```

For adding the role - you use the [`add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles) method on `discord.Member`.

You also seem to be trying to call methods on classes that don't aren't instantiated yet. Using `discord.Member.name` will fail as it's not an instance of that class - you already have an instance of it, `member` in the function arguments so you should be using `member.name` directly. I have fixed that and the similar occurrence in my example. Perhaps consider reading up on [classes in Python](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

Hopefully this is enough to get you going. Can also be expanded for removing the role when a user leaves, etc.

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.
The reason why I was receiving the message as a variable,
I was writing using cog, but Command call in text_channel or user's message is not responding in on_message. So I guess that's why it was a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The `discord.Member.mobile_status` property returns `discord.Status`. It returns `discord.Status.offline` if the user is not on mobile/ is offline. If they are on mobile, it returns the user's current status.

According to the documentation, `discord.Member.is_on_mobile` returns a [boolean](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool).

Other than the problem ESloman has pointed out, `discord.Member.mobile_status.online` doesn't make sense. Instead,

```
if member.mobile_status == discord.Status.online:
    #do something
```

This would only do something if the member is on mobile and has the status `discord.Status.online`

You should be using `member` instead of `discord.Member` because you took `member` as an argument and `discord.Member` is just a class.

If you want to check if the user is on mobile,

```
if member.is_on_mobile():
    #do something
```

[discord.Member.mobile_status](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Member.mobile_status),
[discord.Member.is_on_mobile](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#discord.Member.is_on_mobile)

Comment: Thanks for the further explanation! `is_on_mobile` is a method and not a property though - so your last code block should be `if member.is_on_mobile():`

Comment: thanks for your detailed answer.
The reason I wrote `discord.Member.mobile_status.online` was just to show what results I was predicting.
thanks for the point.